# Spring boot apache camel and apache camel XPATH

Tags: spring, xpath, apache-camel

Apache came XPATH fails when parsing xml file with content .

Please find the route below

```
fromF("file://%s?recursive=true", inputDir)
        .routeId("PollFiles")

        .log("*** file found ${header.CamelFileName}")
        .toF("file://%s?recursive=true",
                archiveDir)
         .log("*** file found ${body}")
         //.convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .choice().when()

       .xpath("//Available[Class='package']").   log("*** found ${body}")
        .end();
```

Error

> org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.w3c.dom.Document with value [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream] due java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/solution//X1.DTD (No such file or directory)

Would appreciate your assistence

Answer (score 1):

It's not xpath related, your error says:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/solution//n (No such file or directory)
```

that means the file supplied to your method does not exist.